# Snapshots for iOS XCode simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, snapshot

Is there any way to save state and just reuse it later, without long restarting the iOS simulator, like you can do with virtualbox? Because it takes a lot of time on my macmini.

Answer (score 1):

No! just keep it running in the background instead

Comment: I can not do this, because appium restarts it every time I start tests.